$f(f(f(x))) = f(x) $ for all x has no solutions if given function is differentiable and non-constant.
Problem:
Prove that there are no nonconstant differentiable functions $$ f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty) $$
that satisfy $$ f(f(f(x))) = f(x) \quad\text{for all }  x \in \mathbb{R}. $$
I've attempted differentiation on both sides, but haven't made progress. Despite trying $$ f^7(x) = f^3(x) = f(x) $$
It hasn't led to a solution. Your insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

What about $f(x)=x$?

John, look at the domain and codomain in the statement question (not the title).

@user43208 Got it!

It seems something like the following approach would work: let $A$ be the image of $f$, which is an interval since $f$ is continuous; note $f\circ f$ is the identity on  $A$, and thus $f|_A$ is either the identity or decreasing. Argue that $A$ must be a closed interval using continuity; then rule out $f$ being the identity on $[a,\infty)$ or $[a,b]$ with $b>a$ by thinking about $f(a-)$; then rule out $f$ mapping $[a,b]$ to $[b,a]$ with $b>a$ by thinking about $f(a-)$ and $f(b+)$ and using the fact that $f$ is its own inverse on $A$. The only possibility left is $A=[a,a]$, so $f$ is constant.

Could you please elaborate, i quite didn't get you
